# Mysql select if MAX val and other condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table in MySql:

```
id|time|depth
```

id and time are primary keys. I need a query to select a row when the depth at the maximum time is not 0.
Ideally I even need the row before maximum.

Let me do an example. The table could be something like this:

```
id       time      depth      
----------------------------
1        0          0   
1        10         1   
1        20         2    
2        0          0     
2        10         1
```

In this case it should return:

```
id       time      depth      
----------------------------  
1        20         2       
2        10         1
```

Thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A join with a subquery is one way of doing it.

```
SELECT a.id, a.time, a.depth FROM Table1 a 
INNER JOIN
  (SELECT id, max(`time`) as mt FROM Table1 WHERE `depth` != 0 GROUP by id)  as b
ON a.id = b.id and a.time = b.mt
```

Comment: He will be in the right track getting the idea you just proposed, but I think this answer will only return the records with `max(time)` which in his example data will be 1 record with time = 20, but I don't know how and what is the logic behind it, but as you can see he needs a query which also returns the record with time = 10 as well

Comment: @EhsanT if you run this in an sqlfiddle with this query you will see that those two rows are returned

Comment: My bad, I had totally ignored `GROUP by`

Comment: Glad to have been of help

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select id,max(time) from test1 where depth<>0 group by id
```